# Include to do or include doing?

Tags: writing, formal-language

Which one is correct?

- The purpose includes to find out which parameter is the most influential.
- The purpose includes finding out which parameter is the most influential.

Comment: The purpose includes finding out which the most influential parameter is. It's not a good idea to use the question form (which parameter is) in embedded clauses.

Answer (score 1):

The second is correct.  After "includes" we use the gerund.

Both sound a little odd because "purpose" usually refers to a single objective while using the word "includes" implies that there are other parts of the purpose aside from finding out which parameter is most influential.

This sounds like scientific writing. Consider instead

> Our objectives include finding out which parameter is the most influential and ...

Or if there is only one purpose, use

> The purpose of this exercise is to determine which parameter is the most influential.

Comment: I think one would always be a flat-out mistake.  Include takes ing.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's right.  I'm often scared to say there is *no* case where it is used.

Comment: Ach, laddie, I ken (or is it lassie?)